# How I can filter invoice with shipdate quickbook sdk c#

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I want to filter invoice with ship date here is my code

```
IInvoiceQuery invoiceQueryRq = requestMsgSet.AppendInvoiceQueryRq();
invoiceQueryRq.IncludeLineItems.SetValue(true);

//want ship date filter here
IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
IResponse response = responseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
IInvoiceRetList invoiceRetList = (IInvoiceRetList)response.Detail;
```

I am able to filter with invoice Modified Date but I am not able to do with ship date. please help me

Answer (score 1):

The `QuickBooks OSR` shows the fields you can filter by:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

Specifically:

```
<InvoiceQueryRq metaData="ENUMTYPE" iterator="ENUMTYPE" iteratorID="UUIDTYPE">
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<TxnID >IDTYPE</TxnID> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<!-- OR -->
<RefNumber >STRTYPE</RefNumber> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<!-- OR -->
<RefNumberCaseSensitive >STRTYPE</RefNumberCaseSensitive> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<!-- OR -->
<MaxReturned >INTTYPE</MaxReturned> <!-- optional -->
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<ModifiedDateRangeFilter> <!-- optional -->
<FromModifiedDate >DATETIMETYPE</FromModifiedDate> <!-- optional -->
<ToModifiedDate >DATETIMETYPE</ToModifiedDate> <!-- optional -->
</ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
<!-- OR -->
<TxnDateRangeFilter> <!-- optional -->
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<FromTxnDate >DATETYPE</FromTxnDate> <!-- optional -->
<ToTxnDate >DATETYPE</ToTxnDate> <!-- optional -->
<!-- OR -->
<!-- DateMacro may have one of the following values: All, Today, ThisWeek, ThisWeekToDate, ThisMonth, ThisMonthToDate, ThisCalendarQuarter, ThisCalendarQuarterToDate, ThisFiscalQuarter, ThisFiscalQuarterToDate, ThisCalendarYear, ThisCalendarYearToDate, ThisFiscalYear, ThisFiscalYearToDate, Yesterday, LastWeek, LastWeekToDate, LastMonth, LastMonthToDate, LastCalendarQuarter, LastCalendarQuarterToDate, LastFiscalQuarter, LastFiscalQuarterToDate, LastCalendarYear, LastCalendarYearToDate, LastFiscalYear, LastFiscalYearToDate, NextWeek, NextFourWeeks, NextMonth, NextCalendarQuarter, NextCalendarYear, NextFiscalQuarter, NextFiscalYear -->
<DateMacro >ENUMTYPE</DateMacro> <!-- optional -->
<!-- END OR -->
</TxnDateRangeFilter>
<!-- END OR -->
<EntityFilter> <!-- optional -->
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<!-- OR -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<!-- OR -->
<ListIDWithChildren >IDTYPE</ListIDWithChildren> <!-- optional -->
<!-- OR -->
<FullNameWithChildren >STRTYPE</FullNameWithChildren> <!-- optional -->
<!-- END OR -->
</EntityFilter>
<AccountFilter> <!-- optional -->
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<!-- OR -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<!-- OR -->
<ListIDWithChildren >IDTYPE</ListIDWithChildren> <!-- optional -->
<!-- OR -->
<FullNameWithChildren >STRTYPE</FullNameWithChildren> <!-- optional -->
<!-- END OR -->
</AccountFilter>
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<RefNumberFilter> <!-- optional -->
<!-- MatchCriterion may have one of the following values: StartsWith, Contains, EndsWith -->
<MatchCriterion >ENUMTYPE</MatchCriterion> <!-- required -->
<RefNumber >STRTYPE</RefNumber> <!-- required -->
</RefNumberFilter>
<!-- OR -->
<RefNumberRangeFilter> <!-- optional -->
<FromRefNumber >STRTYPE</FromRefNumber> <!-- optional -->
<ToRefNumber >STRTYPE</ToRefNumber> <!-- optional -->
</RefNumberRangeFilter>
<!-- END OR -->
<CurrencyFilter> <!-- optional -->
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<!-- OR -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<!-- END OR -->
</CurrencyFilter>
<!-- PaidStatus may have one of the following values: All [DEFAULT], PaidOnly, NotPaidOnly -->
<PaidStatus >ENUMTYPE</PaidStatus> <!-- optional -->
<!-- END OR -->
<IncludeLineItems >BOOLTYPE</IncludeLineItems> <!-- optional -->
<IncludeLinkedTxns >BOOLTYPE</IncludeLinkedTxns> <!-- optional -->
<IncludeRetElement >STRTYPE</IncludeRetElement> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<OwnerID >GUIDTYPE</OwnerID> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
</InvoiceQueryRq>
```

Notice that `ShipDate` is *not* a filterable field. You can't filter by it.

If you want to filter by it, you'll have to pull *all* of the invoices from QuickBooks, and then filter them within your application yourself.